# Eliminar arreglo

Tags: c#

```
static bool elimino(int[] lista, string[] nombre, string nom, ref int tope)
{
    nom = Console.ReadLine()
    bool e = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < tope; i++)
    {
        if (nom == nombre[i])
        {
            for (int j = i; j < tope - 1; j++)
            {
                lista[j] = lista[j + 1];
                nombre[j] = nombre[j + 1];
                tope--;
                e = true;
                i = tope;
            }
        }
    }
    return e;
}
```

asi lo llamo:

```
elimino(vector, nombre, nom,  ref  tope);
```

y tengo esta matriz definida en el main:

```
cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] vector = new int[cantidad];
nombre = new string[cantidad];
int[,] matriz = new int[cantidad, 5];
```

Donde cantidad es el numero de usuarios (nombres) y 5 cada bolilla de lotería

El tema es que ingreso usuario, elimino, pero elimina al usuario, no su apuesta, por ejemplo si tengo 2 usuarios, uno a y otro b, si elimino a, me queda el b con las 2 apuestas, necesito eliminar usuario a con apuesta de a

Comment: ¿Vector y Matriz qué se supone que contienen?

Comment: vector la cantidad de apostantes, la matriz contiene a esos apostantes (cantidad) q son los nombres y 5 el numero de columnas, una por cada bolilla

Comment: No logro entenderlo. ¿Cómo es que guardas la cantidad de apostantes en el vector? ¿Y como que los nombres de los apostantes en la matriz si es de enteros? Si dieran un ejemplo, sería genial.

Comment: un vector con el nombre de cada cliente, vendria a ser las filas de la matriz, vector tiene el largo de filas de cantidad, si la cantidad de apostantes es 10, vector vale 10 y en la matriz se cargn 10 filas, no me referia al nombre, a la cantidad

Comment: @emmanuel-lg edite la pregunte y adjunte como hice el muestro para una guia, me muestra a un cliente y su apuesta, ahora quiero eliminar al cliente y apuesta

Answer (score 0):

Según entendí quieres que en la matriz se elimine la fila completa de apuestas del usuario que se eliminó de la lista de nombres.

Para ello tienes que hacer algo parecido que con `lista` y `nombre`, pero en este caso vas a recorrer hacia atrás filas enteras, no un sólo elemento.
Con un `for` recorres todas las columnas de la matriz y vas asignando esos valores a las mismas columnas pero de la fila anterior.

Otra cosa: la disminución de tope no debería ser dentro del `for`, porque estarías disminuyéndolo muchas veces y sólo se debe eliminar uno, igual el `e = true;`, no es necesario ponerlo ahí, con que cambie una vez cuando encuentre al usuario basta. Además, si `i = tope;` lo pones sólo para que el primer `for` se detenga en ese momento, deberías poner un `break;` en vez de eso.

Te dejo el código corregido:

```
static bool elimino(int[,] matriz, int[] lista, string[] nombre, string nom, ref int tope)
{
    nom = Console.ReadLine()
    bool e = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < tope; i++)
    {
        if (nom == nombre[i])
        {
            for (int j = i; j < tope - 1; j++)
            {
                lista[j] = lista[j + 1];
                nombre[j] = nombre[j + 1];
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < tope; j++)
            {
               matriz[i, j] = matriz[i + 1, j];
            }

            tope--;
            e = true;
            break;
        }
     }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: exacto eso es lo que quiero, modifique el codigo, lo llame asi `elimino(matriz, vector, nombre, nom,  ref  tope);`, pero no me lo esta eliminando, cuando listo los clientes me siguen apareciendo

Comment: Añade a tu pregunta las entradas que utilizas y la salidas que te da.

Comment: ya adjunte las variables que utilizo en el main, quieres que agregue como cargo a los clientes? o sea el metodo?

Comment: No, me refiero a que cuando corres el programa, que usuarios y apuestas ingresas y que te muestra al eliminar.

Comment: ingreso el usuario, luego agrego la apuesta, las 5 bolillas, elimino al usuario y no me da ningun mensaje, cuando lo voy a listar me sigue mostrando al usuario y su apuesta

Comment: recuerdo que hace unos dias me ayudaste con un codigo y funciono, pero ahora cambie la manera de agregar la jugada solamente y que apellido lo saque

Comment: ahi edite la pregunt y añadi un metodo que funciona para ver si se puede adaptar